# Slow days for a full-time consulting job

Tags: consultants

I work remotely as a consultant for a tech company. I also go to college. Last summer I worked 9 to 5 every day, and I was constantly busy with a system they needed built. Over the school year I worked flexible hours, keeping track of each one. The same company offered me the same job for this summer, to maintain the current system. There are some big changes that need to be done coming up, but for various reasons, I cannot start work on these. The system, for the most part, runs itself now, but I'm the only one who understands it or knows how to make changes.

While the company is certainly using my system right now, they haven't asked for many changes lately. Over the past week, I've barely done any programming at all. I've been at my desk during full time hours, but I've mostly been working on other projects because there simply was not anything to do. I'm planning on not billing for these days, because I don't feel morally right doing so. At the same time, I feel I have lost a lot of time. There are countless things I could have done away from my desk during that time. Is this the correct course of action?

One thing that makes this situation even more difficult is that my boss has told me that I can set my own hours if I need to. Normally there was so much to do that this hasn't become an issue, but now it is. Has anyone else seen their full time consulting job turn into a part time one?

Comment: By "set your own hours" did he mean that you could have flex hours - start when you wanted to, even break your day into two four-hour chunks, flex around your other activities - or that your hours would essentially shorten? (Also: you could document the current system, and bill for that time. It's even good practice for your working future - software admins/programmers who document their work thorougly and clearly are very highly appreciated.)

Comment: Leigh, that's a very good point about writing documentation. And about your question: He was mostly highlighting the fact that if I needed to take a few days off for a vacation that I could. However, I believe it was assumed that I would work full time this summer, since I did last summer.

Comment: No bugs to fix, no tests to write?

Comment: Do you think night shift Security guards only Bill for time they catch bad guys? Do Bill! 
Some employees are considered "insurance", in case bad stuff happends. Try to prevent bad stuff by looking through load testing, security, bugs, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask for a meeting with your boss, and work out with them an initial list of tasks/projects that needs to get done.

Since you have so much time available, you might consider getting approval to learn and apply a new technology on the job.

Your boss may have a wish list. You may have a wish list. If your boss doesn't have a wish list, cook one up for him. Ditto if you don't have a wish list.

Look into the firm's operations. Does it have disaster recovery plans in place? Does it have business continuity planning? Is it interested in exploring the cloud? etc.

You may have to look beyond the narrow confines of your job, and your boss may have to look beyond the narrow confines of your job.